# Php convert array to JSON

Tags: php, json

May i ask how to convert an array to JSON format,
I have tried to used the following method, but fail to do so, any idea?

Here's my current result:

```
["B型肝炎疫苗下一個注射期为2017-06-30 ","96709394"]
["疫苗名稱4下一個注射期为2017-06-30 ","96709394"]
```

What i want :

```
{"B型肝炎疫苗下一個注射期为2017-06-30 ","96709394"},
{"疫苗名稱4下一個注射期为2017-06-30 ","96709394"}
```

Thank you

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array( $result )) {

echo "<tr>";
echo '<td>' . $row['id'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['patientid'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['vaccineid'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['vaccinename1'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['totalnoofinjection'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['nthinjection'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['date'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['nextdate'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['skip'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['traditionalmessage'] ."<br />";
echo '<td>' . $row['traditionalmessage'] . '</td>';
echo '<td>' . $row['telMobile'] . '</td>';

$data_array = [$row['traditionalmessage'],$row['telMobile']];
foreach($data_array as $key => $value){
 $new_data_array[urlencode($key)] = urlencode($value);
 }
 $data_json_url = json_encode($new_data_array);

$data_json = urldecode($data_json_url);

echo $data_json;
```

Comment: This `{"疫苗名稱4下一個注射期为2017-06-30 ","96709394"}` is not a valid **JSON**. Do you mean - `{"疫苗名稱4下一個注射期为2017-06-30 ":"96709394"}` ?

Comment: yes, that's right, i'm quite new to programming, and the code don't seems to work. i am thinking whether the named key is missing, as now only the value is showing

Comment: why are you still using the deprecated `mysql_` database library? This was discontinued several years ago due to security concerns and removed entirely in PHP7. If you continue using it you leave yourself vulnerable to hacking, and also when you upgrade to PHP7 eventually, your code will just stop working. I recommend you switch to `mysqli` or `PDO` as soon as possible.